User-defined docker network not automatically added to firewalld zone preventing container to container communication
I have recently (blindly) upgraded my homelab server which lead to some unfortunate side effects. I cannot make two containers on the same network talk to each other anymore when firewalld is enabled. What I have found so far:

Disabling firewalld works

I am testing the communication between 2 containers by adding them a previously created network and pinging the other peer, both by IP and hostname.

If I add the bridge docker interface that represents the docker network on the host to he docker zone on firewalld it works, but I didn't need to do this before.

Affected packages during the upgrade:


base-files bash bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs bluez bluez-obexd containerd.io distro-info-data
  docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin krb5-locales less
  libaom3 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dev libdav1d6 libfreetype6 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-data libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libltdl7 libnss-systemd
  libpam-systemd libpython3.11 libpython3.11-minimal libpython3.11-stdlib libseccomp2 libssl3 libsystemd-shared
  libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-image-amd64 linux-libc-dev locales nano netbird openssh-client openssh-server
  openssh-sftp-server openssl python3-idna python3.11 python3.11-minimal systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  udev zsh

Adding on point #3, what I do is:
docker network create --driver bridge mytestnet
docker run --net mytestnet --name terminal_a -it busybox sh
docker run --net mytestnet --name terminal_b -it busybox sh

My current firewalld config:
➜  sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

docker (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker docker0 docker1
  sources:
  services:
  ports: 8681/tcp 8688/tcp 8088/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 51821/tcp 51820/udp 29811/tcp 29812/tcp 29813/tcp 29814/tcp 27001/tcp 29810/tcp 27001/udp 29810/udp 8043/tcp 6881/udp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

trusted
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:


Docker version 27.1.2, build d01f264
firewalld 1.3.3

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm

I found this relevant issue:It should note that bridge interface may need to be added to a firewall zone with firewalld #11691
